Recovery of a LUKS partition after writing a GPT partition with Windows
I have a storage drive that was a LUKS container setup via cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sda luks. On this drive was a logical volume, and inside the logical volume there was an EXT4 partition. While attempting to format another drive via Windows' unfamiliar GUIs (I didn't have access to a Linux box at the time) I pressed a button to initialize a GPT table on this drive by mistake (I was quite tired). This wrote a small partition to the drive accounting for the first 30MB or so. This LUKS partition then originally spanned the entire drive, and there were no other partitions.
In trying to regain access to my volume, I have written a new partition to the drive using gdisk that covers the whole drive as a LUKS partition following this answer - but I didn't back up the drive, as I lack a drive with the space. This may have been a fatal mistake.
The crux of the question: Is there anything I can do to try to access this drive given this information, or is all hope of data-recovery out of the window?
Running hexdump -C /dev/sda | grep LUKS doesn't return much, but it does return lines like the following:
00e2e4b0  2f 26 00 6a 45 61 97 4c  55 4b 53 b6 1e d4 27 bd  |/8.jEa.LUKS...'.|
649e5d00  18 3f 25 c8 b9 33 18 d7  ac ad 4c 55 4b 53 a5 5a  |.72..3....LUKS.Z|
1542bd130  00 bc 5c 3d 07 43 b0 4c  55 4b 53 50 64 2d a2 c4  |..\=.C.LUKSPd-..|
23f2530c0  ec a5 aa a0 2c ba 15 65  b1 4c 55 4b 53 49 da 0b  |....,..e.LUKSI..|
264443b50  fa 19 49 15 32 70 a0 da  07 4c 55 4b 53 e0 48 d5  |..I.2p...LUKS.H.|

Any guidance would be warmly welcomed, though I do not have much hope. Please let me know if I can provide more details. I have seen this particular answer but I didn't have any results with the linked part one (cryptsetup repair found nothing to work with) and I do not quite understand how to apply part 2 in my case.
An update
I have managed to recover the header and open it with cryptsetup luksOpen --header luks.recovery /dev/loop1 luksrecovery.
This has created two listings in blkid/fdisk -l output:
$ blkid
...
/dev/mapper/vg1-store: UUID="e508d1bf-e90a-4755-940c-705efff3cb3a" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" # the correct name and filesystem of the original partition
...
/dev/loop0: BLOCK_SIZE="1048576" TYPE="squashfs" # the loop device created by losetup
/dev/loop1: PTUUID="14e5f011-0427-4174-9c12-086c53e889c1" PTTYPE="gpt"
...

$ fdisk -l 
...
Disk /dev/loop0: 810.09 MiB, 849440760 bytes, 1659064 sectors
...
Disk /dev/loop1: 10..91TiB, 12000138625024 bytes, 23437770752 sectors
...
/dev/loop1p1 40 23437770711 23437770672 10.9T unknown
...
Disk /dev/mapper/luksrecovery: 10.91 TiB, 12000121847808 bytes, 2929717240 sectors
...
Disk /dev/mapper/vg1-store: 10.91 TiB, 12000117653504 bytes, 2929716224 sectors

If I attempt to mount /dev/mapper/vg1-store, I get an I/O errors:
[ 4631.852531] I/O error, dev loop1, sector 13220482768 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 2 prio class 0
[ 4631.853610] buffer_io_error: 51 callbacks suppressed
[ 4631.853611] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-1, logical block 1652555994, lost async page write
[ 4631.854333] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-1, logical block 1652555995, lost async page write
[ 4631.854921] I/O error, dev loop1, sector 13220482736 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 4631.855496] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-1, logical block 1652555990, lost async page write
[ 4631.856073] I/O error, dev loop1, sector 13220482712 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 2 prio class 0
[ 4631.856651] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-1, logical block 1652555987, lost async page write
[ 4631.857229] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-1, logical block 1652555988, lost async page write
[ 4631.857799] I/O error, dev loop1, sector 13220481744 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 4631.858385] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-1, logical block 1652555866, lost async page write
[ 4631.858965] I/O error, dev loop1, sector 13220481712 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 2 prio class 0
[ 4631.859560] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-1, logical block 1652555862, lost async page write
[ 4631.860144] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-1, logical block 1652555863, lost async page write
[ 4631.860722] I/O error, dev loop1, sector 13195330672 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 4631.861312] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-1, logical block 1649411982, lost async page write
[ 4631.861900] I/O error, dev loop1, sector 13195330600 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 4631.862490] Buffer I/O error on dev dm-1, logical block 1649411973, lost async page write
[ 4631.863088] I/O error, dev loop1, sector 4613769480 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 4631.863691] I/O error, dev loop1, sector 3556805168 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 4631.864278] I/O error, dev loop1, sector 34816 op 0x1:(WRITE) flags 0x800 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 4631.865658] JBD2: journal recovery failed
[ 4631.865662] EXT4-fs (dm-1): error loading journal

I am unsure on the next steps to take, and my searches returned fairly irrelevant seeming results. Thank you all again for your patience and help.

Was this also encrypted? Normally we have partitions, not formatting entire drive without partitions. And Windows always adds its System Reserved partition as first partition with gpt, That is actually unformatted space. But if your volumes were at beginning of drive, not a partition, not sure if you can recovery anything. Always use LInux tools for Linux and Windows tools for Windows to avoid issue. If not encrypted, you may be able to use Photorec to scan drive for anything that looks like a file. But it only finds files by extension and requrires another drive to copy data to.

Use grep keyslots instead (should be at offset 0x5000 if it survived). If there is nothing, then probably not recoverable. No point looking further than the first 1 MiB, if it is as you described and no partition was involved. Even if you find it, your LVM metadata would be toast, hopefully you have a backup of that in /etc/lvm or somewhere (even if it was only a single volume, that filesystem might be toast too, if 30+MB were overwritten...)

Thank you. I have actually managed to recover the header, however I am unsure what to do with it now. Editing with details.

try with mount -o loop,ro ... or debugfs catastrophic mode (just to see if it works at all)
